# Merge one common directory of two different repositories

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two different repositories. What I need to do is to merge one common directory of those. The relative path of this directory is the same for both repositories.

Comment: Merge where? Do you want to merge the info from one into the other, or from each into the other, so both directories are the same at the end, or do you want to merge them both into a new repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these folders don't share a common history in a single git repository (which from your description they do not) you should get a diff tool that supports folder comparison/merge (eg. Beyond Compare) and do the merge manually.